# Why was I supposed to review this as "Looks OK"?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

[Linky](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/13882333)
So apparently I was supposed to review that as <kbd>Looks OK</kbd>.
To elaborate, it was essentially:

> I have this code:
>   *[code]*
>   Something's wrong.

Accordingly, I chose <kbd>Unsalvagable</kbd> -> Should be closed -> Off Topic -> debugging help.

So… why was this chosen as a High-Quality audit?

Comment: This question has been upvoted which gives the audit system the signal that it is a good question. As it is written I would say it is a bad question though.

Comment: The voting on that question is odd. Two upvotes within a minute of it being asked? Four within the first half hour? I don't see any larger-scale coordination involving this user, but maybe someone posted it into a chatroom or got a bunch of coworkers to vote for it.

Comment: That question is fairly clear with some Java specific knowledge. In fact, I think that would've been salvageable even without Java knowledge. Remember, you should see if a question is editable to fix any problems before voting to close.

Comment: Original missing question in the body. Answerer who actually knew the problem edited post into better shape. If you see original version I see how it can be "close as missing problem" (also problem is clearly present in the title), but if audit is actually against latest version I don't see why you'd consider it  wrong. (Proper resolution for question should be duplicate in my opinion as I'd expect this to be very common problem - could be wrong so as I'm not Java person)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question look reasonable to me - the only problem (fixed by later edit by answerer) is missing question in the body of the post (but question present in the title).  If audit shows original version I see how it can be "close as missing problem", but if audit is actually against latest version I don't see why one would consider it low quality.

In final state question is of good quality by itself. Probably should be duplicate as there seem to be plenty of similar questions - https://www.bing.com/search?q=java+run+not+called.

The only concern could be lack of demonstrated research - but that is not the reason to close the question as "unsalvageble" - downvotes/duplicate would be more appropriate.

Comment: Actually, the question [has been edited](//stackoverflow.com/posts/39438958/revisions) (probably from this question drawing attention to itsince I reviewed it. When I reviewed it, it was _very cleary_ missing a problem statement.

Comment: @SomePerson which is exactly what I've said :) Again notice that title was not changed and always contained clear problem statement.